# Excel "IF" function.

Tags: excel, if-statement

If I want to only ask excel to calculate in a cell if TWO other cells have values in them, what is the code?   I know that for it to calculate only if a single cell has a value is =if(A1=0,"",B1-B2)....but how do you add criteria that two cells have a value in them?

Comment: What if the value in `A1` is actually 0? It would be better to define "has value" by using the `ISBLANK` formula.

Answer (score 2):

Example where A1 and B1 are 0:

```
=IF(AND(A1=0,B1=0),"",B1-B2)
```

Comment: If only 1 cells has value?

Comment: Use `OR` instead of `AND`

Answer (score 0):

With this you can verify witch cell has no value

```
=IF(B3="",IF(C3="","both EMPTY","B3 empty C3  with value"),IF(C3="","C3 empty B3 with value","both with value"))
```

You can also set `cell = 0` on the comparison.